# Where to save user information for a mobile Dapp?

Tags: dapp-development, dapps, mobile-wallet

I have been researching on blockchain technology and ethreum platform and I want to build an mobile aplication (Dapp), I know that an Ethereum account has private and public key, the private key only the user's own can use, so my questions are born here. (I know that for this I should have a blockchain network in this case I will use ethereum, I should have a web API and finally the frontend).

1. Where save the user's private key? In a centralized database like a bank data? in the ethereum network?
2. Where save the user's email and password?

or what is the flow exactly about this

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question. The user is going to **bring their own public/private keys** to your Dapp, using an Ethereum client such as [**Mist**](https://github.com/ethereum/mist) or [**Metamask**](https://metamask.io/). When a user visits your Dapp, you will be able to read their Ethereum address *(kind of their public key)*. So you will be able to immediately identify who they are.

Libraries like [**Web3.js**](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/), allow you to interact with their public information *(eg. address, balance, network, numTxs, etc).* Check out the [**Web3 JavaScript app API**](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) for details on what you can do.

Also, if you are concerned about authentication *(as it's trivial to spoof their public key)*, you can use a library like [**Web3-Auth**](https://github.com/vanbexlabs/web3-auth) and ask them to sign a transaction. Only the owner of the real private key will be able to **validate their public address.**

To answer your second question. Non-blockchain data, ie name, email, phone, etc, could be stored in your preferred, traditional data storage (cloud db, rdbms, etc). You could then use `ethereum address` as the key to your user's records when you need to retrieve the information.

---

My advice is that you start with [**My First Dapp**](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop), as the Truffle Framework is ***currently*** the most supported framework for building Dapps. At the end of that tutorial, you should have a much better understanding of how it all works.

**Good luck!**

Comment: so, you are tell me that the client  bring their own public/private keys to my Dapp ie, the client have to have ethereum in his mobile? Really man?

Comment: If you want to build a Dapp, then yes, they need to have a client. The only mobile Dapp client that I know of is https://status.im/, and I think its still in alpha.